# How to add login sound in elementary OS

Tags: greeter, sound

How to add login sound in elementary OS

- default sounds in `/usr/share/sounds`
- custom sounds

Comment: you can go to the system settings->application->startup and add a custom command there to play a file using terminal.
cvlc command works fine on most file types but is a bit slow.
I myself use aplay command but it can only play .wav files

Answer (score 2):

Open System Settings and select Start Up Applications. Click Add.

- In Name call it "Login Sound"
- In Command write `/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --file=YOURFILE`
- In Comment "Play sound on user login"

Obviously, you can use a different name and comment, and replace YOURFILE with the path for your sound.

Comment: sorry, have you tried this?

Comment: If you are having difficulty with some step, can you please explain exactly what your problem is so you can be helped.

Comment: I believe, I tried this before following Ask Ubuntu post. There is No choice to add name and comment.

Comment: I will try again and let you know, thanks for reply. :)

Comment: `canberra-gtk-play` is not installed by default on elementary, I would suggest using `aplay` instead ([via Super User](http://superuser.com/a/511672/481409))